# Cause of "The method 'xa_start' has failed with errorCode '-6'"

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-8

I started working on an application, it's an EJB web service, deployed on IBM websphere 8 and consumes requests from an incoming queue. In the test environments, we frequently get the error  "The method 'xa_start' has failed with errorCode '-6'". I needed some pointers to related documentation to do some root cause analysis. I am doing the usual google search, but has not yielded anything useful

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this IBM support [doc](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21670731), that error code maps to this XA error constant:
-6    XAER_PROTO         Routine was invoked in an improper context.
There are numerous hits in IBM MQ documentation for that error.